# How to choose the correct Amazon-EC2 AMI for a Dockerized Django application?

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use an EC2 instance to host a Dockerized Django application with a postgresql db, and I am having trouble understanding how one would choose an appropriate AMI for this instance.  For starters, does the OS of the instance matter?  I thought the point of Dockerizing an application was so that it can run on any environment.  Once the OS is chosen, how would one decide between the remaining choices?

[Here is an example of some of the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mILPg.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, does the OS of the instance matter?

The instance doesn't mater, but it depends on what your preference is. What you're used to. I always go with the latest Ubuntu LTS. If you're going with Ubuntu the best place to find your image is at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/. I suspect that all the other Linux flavors have a similar page. Just grab the image ID and search for it in Community images.

Once the OS is chosen, how would one decide between the remaining choices?

Once you select it choose your instance size, EBS size etc. This depends on your requirements. You can go as low as micro or as large as 32GB of RAM, or even larger. Depends what you need. I find the T3.large is really good for what I do, but yeah.